# activate the button when trigger the event using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am doing jQuery form validations for blank fields. If any field is blank, i am able to disabling the submit button.

### html

```
    <div class="row popular">
       <div data-val="AXIS"><img src="images/axisbank.gif">
        </div>
       <div data-val="HDFC"><img src="images/hdfcbank.gif">
       </div>
    </div>

   <input name="" type="text" id="banknametxt" placeholder="Select Bank Name">
   <div class="row center bankbt">
      <a href="javascript:" class="bt btblue netBankPay disableClick" id="submitBtn">
      <img src="images/icon_pay.png"> Pay</a>
   </div>
```

If i click on the radio button, i am able to setting the value in the textbox But the button is still disable.(i.e, need to enable the button)

### jquery

```
  $(function() {
    activatePayButton('submitBtn'); 
    $(".popular div").click(function() {
         var nameAttr = $(this).attr('data-val');
          $("#banknametxt").val(nameAttr);
      });

    function activatePayButton(formId){
        $form = $('#'+formId);     
        $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function(event) {                                     
        var disable = false;   
        $form.find("input[type!='hidden']").each(function(i, el) {
           if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
              disable = true; 
           }
        });
        if(disable == true){    
          $form.find('#submitBtn').addClass('disableClick');
         } else{
          $form.find('#submitBtn').removeClass('disableClick');
         }
      });
    }
    });
```

Comment: `$form = $('#'+formId);` point to the button, so, `$form.find("input[type!='hidden']")` return null jquery collection.

Comment: you need to call the change event of the text box manually `$("#banknametxt").change()`

Comment: thanks KishoreSahas..it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing value with `$("#banknametxt").val(nameAttr);` will not invoke `$form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur'` event.

If you want to do so after changing value from jquery use this

```
$("#banknametxt").val(nameAttr);
$("#banknametxt").trigger('change');//manually triggering event
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click binding to the button with `disableClick` class.

```
$(document).on('click','a.disableClick',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```